# Android Studio Open GL ES (errors)

Tags: android

While reading about Open GL for Android Studio, I downloaded the example on 
      https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

And I keep getting tons of errors on the project. I read through the docs on that page... to look for answers. But their isn't.  The errors are just strange. Everything is basically red.  Where it defines the application name is an error. Just everything is.

Comment: You have to post both the code and the errors, otherwise nobody could help you. *EDIT:* yeah, and also before you post it, try to reduce the code to such a small set, as possible. Perhaps it could even get you a hint for how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an older project. What you want to do is open Android Studio and choose import project from IntelliJ/Eclipse project, then go through the wizard to convert everything to Gradle. Also, make sure you have everything you need downloaded from the SDK manager. My Gradle sync failed the first time because I did not have SDK 'android-8' installed. After that, everything worked for me.

[image: part 1]

Be sure to click on the folder just above the app and gradle files. Note that the download link you provided contains two projects in the zip folder, I only did this with the folder HelloOpenGLES20.

[image: part 2]

Name it whatever and click next.

[image: part 3]

Following is the most important step, make sure to check these boxes.

[image: part 4]

If there is still an issue, click on it and it should tell you what to do, then go to your gradle app file and press spacebar in an empty area, then a message will pop up asking if you want to re-sync the gradle file, click yes.